# Evaluating $\int_0^\infty \left( \frac{x}{e^x-e^{-x}}-\frac{1}{2} \right) \frac{dx}{x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis

> Evaluating $$\int_0^\infty \left( \frac{x}{e^x-e^{-x}}-\frac{1}{2} \right) \frac{dx}{x^2}$$

I tried to calculate it by Mathematica, but it failed to give me an answer.

Then I got interested in this problem because it actually can be well evaluated.

**My attempt**

Put
$$
g(x)=\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\right)
$$

Considering that
$$
\left( \frac{x}{e^x-e^{-x}}-\frac{1}{2} \right) \frac{1}{x^2}
=
-\frac{1}{2x}\left(e^{-x}-e^{-2x}\right)
+ g(x)-2g(2x)
$$

and
$$
\int_0^\infty g(x) dx = 2 \int_0^\infty g(2x) dx
$$

thus via Frullani's integral we have
$$
\int_0^\infty \left( \frac{x}{e^x-e^{-x}}-\frac{1}{2} \right) \frac{dx}{x^2}
=
-\frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x}\left(e^{-x}-e^{-2x}\right)
=-\frac{1}{2} \log 2
$$

But I am looking forward to other approaches, beacuse this method doesn't seem quite natural. And I would highly appreciate it if you could share any thoughts on how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This integral is
$$
\frac{1}{4}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x\,\mathrm{csch}(x)-1}{x^2}dx
$$
This function is analytic on $\mathbb R$, but $\mathrm{csch}$ still has an infinite number of poles in $\mathbb C$ at $i\pi \mathbb Z$. The residue at each of these poles is $(-1)^n/(in\pi)$, so doing the standard contour around the upper half-plane gives
$$
\frac{1}{4}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x\,\mathrm{csch}(x)-1}{x^2}dx = \frac{2\pi i}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{in\pi} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n} = -\frac{1}{2}\ln(2).
$$
(This is admittedly trickier than I made it out to be as the error estimates on the contour need to be done more carefully than the usual case, but it's not too hard to work out.)

Comment: It seems to me that you need to be a bit careful in showing that the integral over the semicircle of large radius is $0$ in the limit. What if you accidentally pick a large radius that passes near (or, worse, through) one of the poles?

Comment: @BarryCipra You treat it as the limit of a sequence of contours of radius $(n+1/2)\pi$ to avoid going through a pole. The bigger issue that I glossed over is you need to make separate error estimates near the imaginary axis because the integrand only decays as $1/r$ there.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was getting at. It's been a long time (like almost 50 years) since I've done a contour integral in earnest, but I recall there are occasionally subtle points that need attending to. Experts, of course, know what can be safely glossed over, as here.

Comment: @BarryCipra. Then, you are a young man ! For me 61 years. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, or perhaps we are both young men, and you were a child prodigy. To your health!